# How can I change which day is the first day of the week?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I need to change the first day of the week in asp.net, i.e. I want Saturday to be the first day of the week.

For example, the code below should return 3 on Monday:

```
(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot influence the value of `DateTime.DayOfWeek` as this is a type of `System.DayOfWeek` which is an enumeration (i.e. the values are constant). The definition for `System.DayOfWeek` is in the code block below. So, if you want to treat `DayOfWeek` as though it were `3` on Monday and Saturday to be the first day of the week, then I have to assume you want a 1 to 7 based numbering system. In that case, you can do `((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek+1) % 7 + 1` to get your desired numbers. If you don't need this for calculations, it would be better to just compare the value of `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` to its enum constants (e.g. `if( DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ) ...`).

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies the day of the week.
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Sunday.
    Sunday = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Monday.
    Monday = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Tuesday.
    Tuesday = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Wednesday.
    Wednesday = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Thursday.
    Thursday = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Friday.
    Friday = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates Saturday.
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

Comment: This is good thanks. So, if you want Monday as first day of week it's ((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek+6) % 7 + 1 .... for 1-7 ...or drop the +1 for 0-6 numbering

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code to change the first day of week in an asp.net application.

```
CultureInfo _culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
CultureInfo _uiculture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Clone();

_culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
_uiculture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _culture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _uiculture;
```

Comment: You need `Using System.Globalization`

Comment: Do you know the life this change, would it revert to the previous setting upon the next call to the server? Thanks

Comment: This is also incorrect. As stated below, whatever you do to the current thread culture, the DayOfWeek enum values are constant and will return Sunday=0...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you just need to change the culture your using ([DayOfWeek Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)).

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("ar-EG")
```

Comment: This does not make sense, the DayOfWeek enum will not change because you modify the thread culture. The indexes will remain, Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this C# extension method which returns an zero-based index, based on an alternative first weekday.

`DayOfWeek` defaults to Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, ..., Saturday = 6. We want (ex.) `DayOfWeek` to be Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, ..., Sunday = 6.

Given that the current weekday is Sunday:

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek; // returns Sunday
(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek; // returns 0
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday); // returns 6    

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an zero-based index where firstDayOfWeek = 0 and lastDayOfWeek = 6
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="firstDayOfWeek"></param>
    /// <returns>int between 0 and 6</returns>
    public static int DayOfWeek(this DateTime value, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
    {
        var idx = 7 + (int)value.DayOfWeek - (int)firstDayOfWeek;
        if (idx > 6) // week ends at 6, because Enum.DayOfWeek is zero-based
        {
            idx -= 7;
        }
        return idx;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer

Comment: DayOfWeek is maybe not the best name for such a method as it clashes with the enum DayOfWeek.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            }
        }
```

It really works. Here DayRender is an event.